# Open Street Maps default tiles (Leaflet)

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

Trying the most simple implementation of OSM Leaflet map, [as docs said](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/):

```
import L from 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.js';

var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [51.505, -0.09],
  zoom: 13,
 });
```

Map is rendered with no tiles:

[image]

I think it should be rendered with default tile layer, right?

If I try with another layer provider, it works:

```
 L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}', {
  subdomains: 'abcd',
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 16,
  ext: 'png',
}).addTo(map);
```

How can I render the default tile layer?

Comment: The [docs](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) explicitly state: «It’s worth noting that Leaflet is provider-agnostic, meaning that it doesn’t enforce a particular choice of providers for tiles», which means *there is no default tile layer*.

Comment: So, the first example in this guide does not work by itself? https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/

Comment: The one that says «Let’s create a map of the center of London *with pretty Mapbox Streets tiles*» and «Next we’ll add a tile layer to add to our map, in this case it’s a Mapbox Streets tile layer»? The wording implies that you need to define a tile layer.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in comments, seems that I need to add a layer provider.

I found this tile provider looking at code of [ACF OSM WP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-openstreetmap-field/). It works.

```
https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

Comment: Please read the [tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/) before using tiles from openstreetmap.org.

Comment: The tile usage policy is is well on topic if you don't want to get suddenly blocked.